# Error while unpacking Spring Boot fat jar inside Dockerfile

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am building a Docker container for my Spring Boot application. In order to optimize caching I would like to break up my fat jar generated by Spring Boot into layers. I was able to achieve that by splitting the unpacking process between Gradle file and Dockerfile, but I would prefer to handle everything inside the Dockerfile. My current approach:
Gradle snippet:

```
task explodeJar {
   dependsOn(jar)
   doLast {
      project.delete "$projectDir/build/dependencies"
      project.mkdir "$projectDir/build/dependencies"
      exec {
        workingDir "$projectDir/build/dependencies"     
        commandLine "jar", "-xf", "../libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"
      } 
   }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG DEPENDENCY=/build/dependencies
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","mypackage.MyApp"]
```

When I am running `./gradlew explodeJar` command and then `docker build  -t myapp-spring:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT .` the container builds with no issues, but when I am trying to move the jar extraction into the Dockerfile

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/payouts-spring-${BUILD_VERSION}.jar
ARG DEPENDENCY=/build/dependencies
CMD unzip -d ${DEPENDENCY} ${JAR_FILE}

COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","mypackage.MyApp"]
```

Docker build fails with the error:

```
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN yum install -y java-11-amazon-corretto                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN yum install -y tar unzip procps                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [4/6] COPY /build/dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [5/6] COPY /build/dependencies/META-INF /app/META-INF                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [6/6] COPY /build/dependencies/BOOT-INF/classes /app                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [4/6] COPY /build/dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib:
------
------
 > [5/6] COPY /build/dependencies/META-INF /app/META-INF:
------
------
 > [6/6] COPY /build/dependencies/BOOT-INF/classes /app:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/build/dependencies/BOOT-INF/classes" not found: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a "**no such file or directory**" error.
try running the below command from the location where your dockerfile and target exists.

```
mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: That wasn't it. I adjusted your call to Gradle's folder structure

`mkdir -p build/dependencies && (cd build/dependencies; jar -xf ../libs/myapp-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)`

and it runs OK. The same call inside Dockerfile causes error as above

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by copying the jar into the container and unpacking it there:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN yum install -y java-11-amazon-corretto
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ENV APP_HOME /apps/services
EXPOSE 8080

# unpack and copy folders
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/payouts-spring-${BUILD_VERSION}.jar
ARG JAR_DIR=/build
ARG DOCKER_JAR_FILE=${JAR_DIR}/payouts-spring.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE}  ${DOCKER_JAR_FILE}
WORKDIR ${JAR_DIR}
RUN  jar -xf ${DOCKER_JAR_FILE}

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}

RUN cp -R  BOOT-INF/lib ${APP_HOME}
RUN cp -R  META-INF/* ${APP_HOME}/META-INF
RUN cp -R  BOOT-INF/classes/* ${APP_HOME}


WORKDIR /
RUN rm -r ${JAR_DIR}


ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","apps/services:apps/services/lib/*", "com.myApp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question, but you could also have a look at [jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib). It provides a Gradle plugin and automatically creates a Docker container for you, following Docker layering best practices.